# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_article.created_on

Tags: django, database

I am creating a new model called article in blog app of django. the model is for registered and now want to add some data in all article fields which is defined in model.py file of blog app. Unfortunately, when save button is being clicked, browser comes up with `IntegrityError`.

I tries to look other similar problems with django app, but could not gave me solution.

Here is `blog/models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    author = models.TextField()
    abstract = models.TextField(null=False)
    #publish = models.DateTimeField()
```

Here is `blog/admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import article
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(article)
```

Here is `Traceback`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .
  .
  .
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_article.created_on
[06/May/2019 03:32:46] "POST /admin/blog/article/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 186244
```

Comment: Any of your migrations are pending to migrate, in which `created_on` field use?

Comment: Hello shafik, thank you for your response. Did not use `created_on` field.

Comment: run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command. Then try again

Comment: solved. Thanks a lot.